# Unauthorized Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, unauthorized

I am programing a Springboot api rest but i have a problem with Spring security.
When i want to Make a request to the server , it throws Unauthorized 401 but i have already configured spring security. Here is the code:

```
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/characters/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}



@Override
@Bean
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

    UserDetails admin= User.builder().username("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("123")).roles("ADMIN")
            .build();

    UserDetails user= User.builder().username("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("123")).roles("USER")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin,user);
}
```

}

Request method:

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value ="/characters"  ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<ImagenNombreDTO> listarPersonajes(){
    try {
        return personajeService.listarPersonajes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes inside antmatchers() method of SecurityConfig.java file.

Add one more entry of "/characters" endpoint like following and see whether the error still persists or not.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/characters","/characters/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```